# Why following AES encryption and decryption is working in main method but not on client side server?

Tags: java, aes

Not only the above encrypted string is not able to decrypt from client end. But also, it is not able to be decrypted in the following website.
https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption

the error I am getting when I try to decrypt on the above website is

error: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.

P.S: I am setting secret key as static for testing purposes.

```
package com.snapwork.util;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;
 
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import com.sun.mail.util.ASCIIUtility;

import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
 
public class AES {
 
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key ;
    private static byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    private static IvParameterSpec ivspec;
    

 
public static void setKeyAndIV(String myKey) 
{
    MessageDigest sha = null;
    ivspec = new IvParameterSpec("39d0a599ea7c1761".getBytes());
   
    try {
        key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret) 
{
    try
    {
        setKeyAndIV(secret);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) 
{
    try
    {
        setKeyAndIV(secret);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final String myKey = "8e990516e545ba4103dcb32a3462c54b";
    
    String fullName = "ANURAG"; String mobileNumber = "9930858174"; String
      emailId = "xyz@gmail.com"; String custIdentifier = "4127672700000765";
      String availableCredits = "9815646465"; String eligibleOfferTag = "94913";
     
     
     
    String inputString = fullName + "|" + mobileNumber + "|" + emailId + "|" + custIdentifier + "|" + availableCredits + "|" + eligibleOfferTag;
    String decryptedString = AES.encrypt(inputString, myKey) ;
     
    System.out.println(decryptedString);
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What error message is given on client side. Second: what Java version is running on client side ?

Comment: The decryption on the named website cannot work as the website awaits ASCII-values for the key and the iv but your program is working with bytes (hex-string). The good news are - your encryption and decryption is working fine but only the first problem (not running on client side) persists.

Comment: @MichaelFehr It seems client is not using the below line
key = sha.digest(key);
sha.digest might be modifying key, so I couldn't decrypt the string using that key on devglan websit.
so, I commented that line. Now it is working fine. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I just commented this line `key = sha.digest(key);` , and it started working.
The issue could be client is not using that line. That line could be modifing static secret key, So I couldn't decrypt on devglan website

Anyways, Thank you all for suggestions.